# Should we gently take away thing from a baby's hands before she can eat them?

Tags: infant, discipline, safety, mouthing

My almost 1-year-old baby grabs whatever she can from the ground and tries to eat it.

- Should we take it gently from her and tell her "No"?
- Should we "hit" it out of her hand with a finger, I am worried doing this may seem a bit violent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that this is dependent on the item your child is trying to "eat"

My daughter is also of an age where everything goes into her mouth, but this is partly a child's way of exploring and learning about the world. Shes put toy's, an Xbox controller and even the dogs ear in her mouth at one point or another so the act of putting something into their mouth isn't in itself a bad thing. The issue would be if there's a danger i.e a choking hazard, sharp, toxic etc.

My daughter will often watch for my reaction while doing this and usually a short

> NO or "Ah"

is enough. Occasionally she'll test her boundaries and will need the item removed from her hands. This can be done gently if the item isn't a hazard or she's testing you. You may find that she'll move her head or body to continue to try and eat the item as you're moving it away.

If on the other hand it was say a shard of glass she was intent on eating then a sharp pat to the hand may be appropriate. We feel pain as a way of protecting ourselves from danger, and the shock of having their hand patted away form their mouth provides the lesson that what they were doing was dangerous without the risk of letting them eat the glass (or other dangerous item)

Please note i'm not advocating hitting the child or anything like that, just swiftly changing their arm position to give them a small shock and changing their thought process.

To sum up, as long as it's safe i wouldn't worry too much, if its dangerous then do what you need to to protect her.